# use the result of return file() of a controller as src of image tag in another view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller DisplayImage which return binary file and i can see the result in its view without any 
problem,
but i want use the result of this controller in image view as a partial view but it is not possible
as when i call the html.partial(_partialview) the model which have been passed to partial , is index model

let me show my code:

```
    public ActionResult DisplayImage(int id = 1)
    {
        Product product = db.Product.Find(id);
        return File(product.Blob, "image/png");

    }
```

and

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Product.ToList());
    }
```

and in index view i wrote:

```
    @Html.Partial("_DisplayImage")
```

and in partial view i wrote:

```
    <img style="width:60px" src="@Url.Action("DislpayImage", "Product", new { id="1" })"     alt="myimage" />
```

also if i use the img tag directly in index view still doesn't work and the result is :

```
    <img alt="myimage" src="/Product/DislpayImage/1" style="width:60px">
```

without any image
so what can i do with this problem

I hope describe my problem clear
If not, please ask!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your action name.

> DislpayImage

is not the same as

> DisplayImage

```
<img style="width:60px" src="@Url.Action("DisplayImage", "Product", new { id="1" })"     alt="myimage" />
```

Comment: @mehdy - no problem, it happens to us all!  Remember to accept the answer if it helped fix your problem :)